# Cannot redirect properly in PHP

Tags: php, session

i have place this code in header file

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['user'])){
    if($_SESSION['user'] == 'admin'){
        header('Location:admin.php');
        exit;
    }
    if($_SESSION['user'] == 'user'){
        header('Location:user.php');
        exit;
    }
}
```

My login file save session values like this

```
$result=$stmt->fetchAll();
$_SESSION['id'] = $result[0]->Id;
$_SESSION['user'] = 'user';
```

### on index page header file works correctly but on user.php page it is giving error cannot redirect properly.

Actually problem is that on successful login it redirect to user page but it is checking again and again for session['user'] which is always 'user'. but redirecting on the same page user.php. i want a flag like thing to stop redirect it.

Comment: Add the complete error message. My guess would be that you’re outputting something before the redirect.

Comment: Error is not about header message like already sent -------------------
-
The page isn’t redirecting properly 
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that code is in your header file, and user.php uses that header file, then you are stuck in an infinite redirect loop.  You redirect to user.php who's header redirects you to user.php, etc...  There doesn't appear to be any code that says "okay, stop redirecting now".

I would suggest one of a few things, in order of decreasing preference:

1. Only redirect from the page that needs to redirect: don't put your redirect logic in the header.php file used by the entire site
2. Once you redirect, set a flag denoting that the redirect has happened, and check for it before redirecting.
3. Use a separate header file for the user.php that doesn't include the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

First, this statement:

```
if(isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['user'])){
```

is equivalent to (and easier to read as) just:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
```

Second, you should only include this part of the code (the redirection) on your actual login page / controller. Since how it's written now, a logged in user will only be able to access `admin.php` or `user.php`.

Move the redirection code to `login.php` and keep it outside of your header file.

If that means changing the action of your login form to `login.php`, that's the correct part for the login code as well (and not in your header file).

Comment: how could other scripts like wordpress or any other manage one file to redirect the user ?
You mean i must use two header files or logics or pages name like if (login.page execute this code) if another page use this code

Comment: Sure, you can check the value of (with basename if necessary) `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`. Those values have slightly different meaning, but will be able to tell you which script is running. But in general, you probably want to use a proper routing script instead (running as a single, exposed `index.php`), and handle those requests in specific controllers.